# spliturl function appending twice

Tags: javascript, function, split

here's the code:

```
function chatWin(url,name){
    var nw;
    var splitUrlResults = url.split("#");

    url = appendDataWakeNVPs(splitUrlResults[0]) + '#' + splitUrlResults[1] ;

    nw=window.open(url,name,"height=600,width=433,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,status=no");

    if (nw.focus) {nw.focus();}
}
```

and then the link in the code:

```
PROD_TAB_EXPRT_LNK_EMAIL=javascript:chatWin('/customerService/contactUs/help.html#1','Help')
```

but the rendered code is:

```
<a href="javascript:chatWin('/customerService/contactUs/help.html#0#1','Help');">
```

Every link is getting #0 appended before the tab identifier- (#1 in this case).

thoughts?

Comment: I don't know what the `PROD_TAB_EXPRT_LNK_EMAIL` bit means, but it looks like it's whatever this is a part of that's putting in the extra `#0`, as opposed to the javascript. From your question, it looks like it's the *parameter* to the `chatWin` function that's being messed up, as opposed to the output of the `chatWin` function. Maybe you need to escape the `#`?

Comment: What does `appendDataWakeNVPs()` do?

Comment: to be honest, I have no idea what appendDataWakeNVPs does. This site is huge, so to track down a function is near impossible sometimes

Comment: and PROD_TAB_EXPRT_LNK_EMAIL is in a properties file which the jsp is using. The link is correct, but I will try and escape the #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the only way url ends up with `#0#1` on the end of it is if `appendDataWakeNVP()` is appending `#0` onto it's return value and your code is then adding the `#1` onto the end of that.

So, I think your problem is in `appendDataWakeNVP()`.  I'd suggest stepping into that function in your favorite debugger and you can discover what it does.  Or grep for it in your source tree and examine it in your editor.  If it's suppose to add `#0` onto the end and you can't change that, but you don't want that there, then you will have to remove that before appending your own hash onto the end of it.

Any hash value you don't want can be removed with this:

```
url = url.replace(/#.*$/, "");
```

So, you could change this line of code:

```
url = appendDataWakeNVPs(splitUrlResults[0]) + '#' + splitUrlResults[1] ;
```

to this:

```
url = appendDataWakeNVPs(splitUrlResults[0]).replace(/#.*$/, "") + '#' + splitUrlResults[1] ;
```

Comment: gave you credit for a good answer. The truth is, it turned out that there were several different places within the jsp's and jsi's that were handling the hash.